# flask mail "running out of context error" even with context

Tags: python, email, flask, celery

I am trying to send mail in a celery task using flask-mail, however I continue to get this runtime error `RuntimeError('working outside of application context',)`. This is the code I have in the file itself:

```
from app import app
from celery import Celery
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from flask import current_app

# config
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# set up celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

# put the processing task here
@celery.task
def send_results(filename, email_addr):
    msg = Message('testing email', recipients=[email_addr])
    msg.body = 'testing this funct'
    with app.app_context():
        current_app.mail.send(msg)
    print(filename)
    print(email_addr)
```

Note that it has the `app.app_context()` line in there (At this point I'm not sure if it's right or not)

Another thing to note is that the app isn't fully "completed" yet. Specifically what I mean by this is that the creation of the app is handled by a function called create_app as seen here: https://github.com/swarajd/seq2flux/blob/master/app/startup/create_app.py

That function is called in manage.py here: https://github.com/swarajd/seq2flux/blob/master/manage.py

I try to call this task in a file called `views.py` which handles all the views. The one function in particular that deals with this is as follows:

```
@core_blueprint.route('data_analysis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def data_analysis():

    # print(request.form)
    form = DataAnalysisForm(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form)))

    # print(form)

    if (request.method == 'POST' and form.validate()):

        # print(request.form)
        # print(request.files)
        file = request.files['seqFile']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        mail_engine = current_app.extensions.get('mail', None)
        # print(mail_engine)

        # print(current_user)
        send_results.delay(filename, current_user.email)


        flash('processing job scheduled!')

        # Redirect to home page
        return redirect(url_for('core.data_analysis'))


    return render_template('core/data_analysis.html', form=form)
```

The important line is: `send_results.delay()`

My question is: even with context, why is it throwing that runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening was because the email MESSAGE itself was being created outside the `with` statement, causing the runtime error.